# menustrip issue on visual basic in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPvzs.png)
why my menustrip doesnt show text or uneditable

Comment: Have you try clicking that small triangle on top right and select "Insert Standard Items"?

Comment: i have but it was uneditable menustrip